# Single role multiple hosts different tasks

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with multiple tasks for a single role, i want to divide the tasks   say 80% to first host and remaining 20% to second host , the first and second host will be picked from

```
ansible-playbook -i 1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5, update.yml
```

where `1.2.3.4` is first server ip and `2.3.4.5` is second server ip. How can i achieve this.

Comment: Just don't do this.

Comment: :( any other suggestions for this?

Comment: Describe original problem (use case) why do you ever want to execute 80% of *tasks* on one host and 20% on another?

Comment: I have 10 tasks, of which 6 should be executed in server 1 and 4 should be executed  in server 2 but they belong to same role and server 2 should be executed after server 1 execution

Comment: Please give *real* example of those tasks. In 99.9% use cases a role is non-splittable logical unit.

Comment: I do not agree with the statement "In 99.9% use cases a role is non-splittable logical unit". [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html) allows to include *tasks_from* single file. This use-case makes a role kind of a dynamic library.

Comment: What's wrong with using `delegate_to` on the tasks?

Comment: @Jack how would i choose on which IP the certain task would go

Comment: @windowws `ansible-playbook -e host1=1.2.3.4  -e host2=2.3.4.5 update.yml` and then have `delegate_to: "{{host1}}` or `delegate_to: "{{host2}}"` on each play.

Answer (score 1):

To recap:
You have one role with 10 tasks. 6 of which you want to execute on server 1 and the rest on server 2

A way would be to write 2 different playbooks which will include the tasks you want to execute on the specified hosts.
Another might be to use tags on each task and execute ansible with --tags and specify them on playbook level

```
- hosts: all
  tags:
    - foo
  role:
    ...

- hosts: all
  tags: 
    - bar
  role:
    ...
```

ref https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html

Comment: I am getting the IP of server using the -i option, so how could i differentiate the server 1 and server 2

Comment: Since 2.4 ansible supports use of host_list in its command see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/host_list.html

running ansible-playbook -i '<server 1 ip>, <server 2 ip>' playbook.yaml should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Playbook tasks execution can be controlled by tags or blocks. My previous answer was related to the task execution on few of the hosts(I miss understood)

For eg.
serial: "80%"

would mean that all the tasks will be performed on 80% of the hosts first then will be performed on the remaining hosts.

For playbook to execute some tasks on few hosts and some on few hosts you can may be use when with ansible_hostname set to some hosts

Comment: i dont get you, can you please elaborate if this is relevant